# Visual Basic Web Project - ASP.net

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I'm a computer science student.  I just completed my first web project using Visual Basic.  The project runs fine on my local machine.  I had access to a server and used the Publish button in Visual Studio to upload the project to a server.  All the files seem to have uploaded correctly, but when I view the project, I only get text/code and never see the page I created?

Any idea what I am missing here?  Here is the directory:

http://pregnancywebsite.net/test/

Thanks in advance!

Brent

Comment: http://pregnancywebsite.net/ ?

Comment: What is the page you created if it is default.aspx right click in solution explorer and set it as start page.

Comment: http://pregnancywebsite.net/test/Default.aspx is the page.  I tried setting it as the start page and republishing, but that did not fix the problem.  When viewed locally, it seems to work fine, the problem is only when viewed on the server.